# Compacting Webhelp Documentation (Robohelp 8)

Tags: robohelp

I'm trying to find a way to compact Robohelp 8 projects so that when I upload a Webhelp documentation to a customer server it doesn't contain thousands of files.  Is this possible?  Any suggestions for compiling projects to a smaller size?

Answer (score 0):

WebHelp isn't really "compiled". The generated WebHelp output has the same files as in the RoboHelpsource - the HTML pages, images, and baggage files you've included. The differences in the HTML pages include, for example, actual content instead of the User Defined Variables and Snippets in the source.
Plus there are a lot of HTML, XML, JavaScript and image files for navigation, index and glossary.

Adobe's info on those output files, specifically for RoboHelp 11: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/robohelp/robohtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11aff59c2a0-7fb6.html